# RF Cable testing-- Ripples during S21 measurement

Tags: rf

During the testing of RF cables, I am seeing ripples during S21 measurement. It is almost straight till 2.5GHz, but between 2.5GHz and 3GHz unit is showing ripples .

May I know the reason for this phenomenon?

Comment: Have you ever tried this: on a cheap cable measure S21 over cable length (plot of X = distance, Y = S21). Then bend and straighten it a few times in the middle. Now measure S21 again. You will see lots of S21 ripples at the distance where you bended the cable. Lesson learned: cables are very sensitive to bending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two mechanisms that can cause a cable to have ripples in S21:

Discontinuities in the characteristic impedance of the cable causes reflections of the electromagnetic wave in the cable. These reflections cause [standing waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_wave) as they go through constructive and destructive interference, and this causes ripples to appear in S21. The frequency axis of S21 corresponds to different wavelengths of the electromagnetic wave. As the wavelength changes through the frequency sweep, the location of the nulls in due to destructive interference changes. The S21 plot is showing that the energy is not propagating from the input to the output of the cable. Instead, you will probably see most of this energy that is missing from the nulls being reflected back to the input port. This would cause ripples in S11 that correspond to the ripples in S21. If S11 does not show a pattern of ripples that corresponds to the S21 variation, then the energy is being absorbed somewhere, not reflected.

The discontinuities can have many root causes. One of the most common causes is the connectors. As mentioned in the other answer, it is instructive to see this effect by creating intentional discontinuities in the cable. I gained intuition by looking at a network analyzer display while bending a cable, and then pinching the cable in a vise until it broke. You could also try hitting the connector with a hammer.

Another mechanism for ripples could be a mode of wave propagation other than the [fundamental TEM mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_mode). These modes can be in the cable or the connectors. A common way to avoid this problem is to use thinner coax cables and smaller connectors at higher frequencies.

Answer (score 2):

If your network analyzer is well-calibrated:

The reason for you seeing ripples is probably because there are actually ripples in the S21.

This might have different reasons; most likely, a non-perfect impedance match introduces reflections at the connectors, and that in turn leads to standing waves, which, for some frequencies will cancel out the signal (hence reduce S21) and for others overlay constructively.

But: without knowing a lot more, it's also totally possible that there's actual frequency-selectiveness in the cable, eg. by polarization losses in the dielectric. I'm not aware of any material that would have changing losses between 2.5 GHz and 3 GHz.

Comment: Don't you mean below the frequency of water absorption? [It peaks at 24 GHz or so](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Dielectric_loss_water.png) and is quite smooth.

Comment: Err, yeah. removing that. Got absorption/dielectric losses mixed up with usage as microwave heating frequency